# Can I install Linux on a Macbook?

Tags: linux, macbook, liveusb, icloud

I would like to install Linux on a Macbook. There are several reasons for that: I like the design, keyboard, and tactile sensations Macbooks give, but I use Linux for both work and hobbies. So I'm wondering whether I need to buy a normal new/used Macbook or I can buy a locked one, that is much cheaper.

Is it possible to simply plug in a bootable USB stick and boot into Linux? Or replace the hard drive with another one with Linux installed?

Comment: I can't think of many reasons why someone would sell a (much cheaper) locked device other that it being stolen.

Comment: Yeap, it was definitely stolen, but I'm not saying it is good to buy a stolen device and use it, it's not ethical, obviously. The right thing to do is to return the device to a previous owner. Also, I'm not saying I will do that, the deeper I go into this theme, the closer I am to buying a normal Windows-running pc and installing Linux then.

Comment: New Macs are locked solid. If you buy a stolen one you may as well buy a brick.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yeap, you are right, I spent about a day to understand that buying a locked Mac is a very very bad idea, thank you. So now I'm locking on a new/used Macbook with an Intel chip or some Windows laptop, like DELL XPS or smth.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it is possible. Just be certain of who you are buying from and proceed with caution. Replacing the hard drive with linux installed could work but it is best to do a fresh boot via USB so you ensure all the proper drivers are there.

Comment: If it's pre 2012 yes. Much harder between then & 2016. Not a hope on a new Mac. Can't replace the drive either.